# I want to create a real-time peak detection algorithm for PPG using C# code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently a master's student studying bio-signal.
I want to use PPG equipment to detect the peak of real-time PPG, but it's too difficult to detect the peak in data measured by Matlab, so I'm asking for an algorithm or code.
It's my first time making a code with C#, so if this question is rude to you, I'd like to apologize in advance. Thank you.

```
IEnumerator ReceivePPG()
{

    while (true)
    {
        int receivedNumber = serialPort.BytesToRead;

        if (receivedNumber > 0)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[receivedNumber];
            serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, receivedNumber);


            int dataIndex = 0;

            foreach (byte receivedData in buffer)
            {
                if (Parsing_LXDFT2(receivedData) == 1)
                {


                    int i = 0;
                    int streamdata = ((PacketStreamData[i * 2] & 0x0F) << 8) + PacketStreamData[i * 2 + 1]; //PPG 데이터

                    listPPG.Add((float)streamdata);

                    float[] ppgArray = listPPG.ToArray();

                    // ppg 개수가 windowsize 만큼 뺄수 있게 되고부터 실행
                    //Debug.Log(ppgArray.Length);

                    if ((ppgArray.Length - windowsSize + 1) >= 0)
                    {

                        PeakDetection(ppgArray);
                        //WriteCSVSSF(ppgArray);
                        //WriteCSVRAW(ppgArray);

                    }


                }
            }
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
    
}

string filename_SSFPPG = "";
string filename_RAWPPG = "";
void Start()
{
    SerialOpen();
    StartCoroutine(ReceivePPG());
    filename_SSFPPG = Application.dataPath + "/SSFPPG.csv";
    filename_RAWPPG = Application.dataPath + "/RawPPG.csv";

}

void Update()
{

}





// PPG신호를 SSF신호로 변환하는 함수
static float[] ConvertToSSF(float[] ppgSignal)
{

    // SSF 신호를 저장할 배열
    //Debug.Log(ppgSignal.Length);
    float[] ssfSignal = new float[ppgSignal.Length - windowsSize + 1];

    // SSF 계산
    for (int i = 0; i < ssfSignal.Length; i++)
    {
        float sum = 0;
        // 윈도우 크기만큼의 샘플을 합산
        for (int j = 0; j < windowsSize; j++)
        {
            sum += ppgSignal[i + j];
        }

        // 평균 계산하여 SSF에 저장
        ssfSignal[i] = sum/windowsSize;
    }

    return ssfSignal;


}

//실시간 피크 검출 알고리즘
static void PeakDetection(float[] ppgData)
{
    float[] ppgArray = ppgData.ToArray();
    float[] ssfSignal = ConvertToSSF(ppgArray);
    List<float> ssfPeaksBuffer = new List<float>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ssfSignal.Length; i++)
    {
        float ssfPeak = ssfSignal[i];
        ssfPeaksBuffer.Add(ssfPeak);

        // 버퍼의 크기가 제한 내에 유지되도록
        if (ssfPeaksBuffer.Count > BufferSize)
            ssfPeaksBuffer.RemoveAt(0);

        //임계값을 업데이트
        float threshold = GetAdaptiveThreshold(ssfPeaksBuffer);

        if(ssfPeak > threshold)
        {

        }
    }
}

// 적응적인 임계값을 얻는 함수
static float GetAdaptiveThreshold(List<float> ssfPeaksBuffer)
{
    //초기 임계값을 최대 피크의 백분율로 계산
    float initialThreshold = InitialThresholdRatio * ssfPeaksBuffer.Max();

    //버퍼 정보를 활용하여 임계값 조정
    float adjustedThreshold = initialThreshold;

    return adjustedThreshold;
}
```

The code above is the code I wrote so far.

Comment: Using domain-specific TLAs, especially from niche domains, will significantly _decrease_ probability of getting helpful answers. It is your duty to make yourself clear what you are asking about.

Comment: But alas: Since neither Windows nor C#/.Net have (hard) Real-Time-Capabilities, we need to agree on that here, the [term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) is meant to be read as referring to the "soft" variety of "Real-Time" or more like "as fast as possible", right? I'd also strongly suggest to refrain form using non-english comments. It just make them unusable for a significant portion of fellow coders that are not fluent in Korean ;)

Comment: To your problem: Can you elaborate on what algorithm you tried to implement in that code? I would have expected to see something like a first derivative of the signal being checked for Zero-Crossings...

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I want to explain in detail how this code works and what format I want to work out the algorithm. If you don't mind, I'd appreciate it if you could let me know your email. Sorry for using this site for the first time.

Comment: Let's keep it on-site. Just improve your question and I am pretty confident you'll get help. Get some inspiration on improvements from [ask].